# I get the "JAVA_HOME is not set" error even though I have correctly set it (while trying to install Vagrant)

Tags: java, windows, vagrant, virtualbox, java-home

I am trying to install a java project. I have downloaded Vagrant and VirtualBox. I am following the steps [here](https://github.com/tobias-dv-lnu/1dv600-lab/wiki/Installation-and-Deployment) to setup the project I will be working on.

This is what I get when I execute the "vagrant up" command in cmd:

```
c:\Users\Giannis\Desktop\1dv600-lab-java>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
    default: ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
    default:
    default: Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
    default: location of your Java installation.

The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Now, when run the following commands in a cmd window

```
java -version
javac -version
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

I receive the messages I should receive.
So what is wrong with my Java installation?

Comment: which version of java installed?

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` execution that fails is executed in your VM,that means that java is not installed, while it exists in your hosts systems (windows). You need to install/provision java in your vm so it can work.

Comment: I didn't think of that Dimitri, thank you a lot for your suggestion!